# Embedded absolute div and z-index

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I try to implement a dropdown-menu, that can be re-used in different divs.

I use `position:relative` for the dropdown menu(so it will appear under the button that is opening it). The problem is, that the dropdown menu is only overlaying it's parent divs: if the dropdown menu overlaps to an another (not parent) div, no matter the z-index I set, it underlays.

Is there a solution to make the absolute positioned item to be over everything else?

(I must use the z-indexes for other reasons, and I cannot make the menu display:relative)

```css
.back, .front, .back2{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.back {
  position:relative;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  background: red;
}
.back2 {
  position:relative;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 50px;
  left: 20px;
  background: orange;
}

.front {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:20;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
  <span >Parent div1</span>
  <div class="front">
    <span >dropdown</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="back2">
  <span >someOtherDiv</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to give z-index in parent div. Check updated snippet below

```css
.back, .front, .back2{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.back {
  position:relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  background: red;
}
.back2 {
  position:relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 20px;
  background: orange;
}

.front {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:20;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
  <span >Parent div1</span>
  <div class="front">
    <span >dropdown</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="back2">
  <span >someOtherDiv</span>
</div>
```

> As per your question you can't remove `z-index` from `parent div` in that case you can update greater `z-index` to `parent div`. 
>   Check updated snippet below...

```css
.back, .front, .back2{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.back {
  position:relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  background: red;
  z-index:10;
}
.back2 {
  position:relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 20px;
  background: orange;
  z-index:9;
}

.front {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:20;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
  <span >Parent div1</span>
  <div class="front">
    <span >dropdown</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="back2">
  <span >someOtherDiv</span>
</div>
```

Comment: for other reasons(not related to this problem), I must use the z-index property on the parent div. Is there a way to solve this problem without removing that?

Comment: thanks, it is a solution I was looking for. 

Although as you pointed out on the first question, if there would be no z-indexes, I wouldn't have a problem... so I am considering removing z-index solutions from the project, they doesn't seem like a good practice to widely use.